# How to uninstall LightScribe Control Panel?

Tags: windows-7, windows, lightscribe

In the notification area of my taskbar I found LightScribe Control Panel. What is it ? What does it do ?

Should I have to keep it. When I tried to uninstall it, there was no such entry in the Programs and Features of Control Panel. How to uninstall it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightscribe is a feature of some disc burners - it allows you to burn an image on the other side of the disc, after you flip it.  Your drive must support this feature for it to work.

It may be part of a disc burning suite on your system.

Comment: What happens if I uninstall it ?

Comment: What you mean by other side of disc ?

Comment: "Direct Disc Labeling" is what it's also termed.  Basically you can burn a monochrome label or picture image on the other, non-data side of the disc.  You also need special LightScribe discs as well.  If your drive is not LightScribe featured or you don't want to use LightScribe, you can remove this or the suite that installs it.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether my drive is LightScribe featured ?

Comment: If it's not an HP disc burner it's likely not.  The LightScribe Control Panel ought to tell you.

Comment: My drive is not LightScribe featured. How can I uninstall it ?